# Windows Application Guideline

Tags: applications

Is there a guideline for designing Windows Applications, whereas they specify font size and spacing, best screen resolution?

Comment: The first and second results on the first page for Google search provide the right answer to this question, as checked today.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, of course MS has its own user interaction guidelines and they are available online: [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking out for an older version of the Windows guidelines - which had more actionable detail:

Here's a link to them in book form:

[The Windows Interface Guidelines for Software Design](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/books/thewindowsinterfaceguidelinesforsoftwaredesign)

*Scroll down for the Contents list...*

Microsoft used to have these on their website - but I can't find them now.